# Is there any way to build Angular project in "check" mode (bundle not needed)?

Tags: angular, optimization, build, pull-request, cicd

Im looking for a way to optimize or replace `ng build` command in CI/CD pipeline for Pull Requests, where we only need to make sure everything compiles, but the artifacts are not used. Is there some way to skip preparing actual files?